# Dictionary comprehension returning ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, valueerror, dictionary-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries with hundreds of entries like this

```
lst = [{'A':'0.1'},{'B':'0.1'},{'C':'0.01'},{'D':'0.0001'},{'E':'0.01'}]
```

I am trying to sort the key:value pairs into separate lists using dictionary comprehension

```
lst1 = []
lst2 = []
lst3 = []
lst1.append({key:value for (key,value) in lst if value == '0.1'})
lst2.append({key:value for (key,value) in lst if value == '0.01'})
lst3.append({key:value for (key,value) in lst if value == '0.0001'})
```

I am then using an if statement to check what list a certain key is in.

```
variable = 'A'
if variable in lst1:
    print('A is in lst one')
```

When i run the code I get ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Does each dictionary in the list contain exactly one key ?

Comment: yes just one key per dictionary

Comment: You can't unpack a dictionary with (key, value) which only works on a tuple. Maybe try something like this: https://akuiper.com/console/2LMfDvhZ4Fhm. But I can see that your data structure is not optimal for the result you are looking for.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a name for a variable, it's already the name of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use `list` as a name. It's the name of a built-in class and you don't want to overwrite it.

What you're trying to do is something like this:

```
lst = [{'A':'0.1'},{'B':'0.1'},{'C':'0.01'},{'D':'0.0001'},{'E':'0.01'}]

list1 = [dic for dic in lst if list(dic.values())[0]== '0.1']
list2 = [dic for dic in lst if list(dic.values())[0]== '0.01']
list3 = [dic for dic in lst if list(dic.values())[0]== '0.0001']

print(list1)
print(list2)
print(list3)
```

outputs:

```
[{'A': '0.1'}, {'B': '0.1'}]
[{'C': '0.01'}, {'E': '0.01'}]
[{'D': '0.0001'}]
```

Note that `list(dic.values())` wouldn't have made any sense (it would produce an error) had I overwritten `list`.

And later:

```
variable = 'A'
for item in list1:
    if variable in item.keys():
        print('A is in list one')
```

which can be encapsulated in a function:

```
def find_key(variable):
    for item in list1:
        if variable in item.keys():
            print(f'{variable} is in list one')

find_key('A')
A is in list one
```

Now, do you really need to use dictionaries with one key, value pair each one? Do you need to store those in a list? I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but seems like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Try to think whether there is a simpler, more elegant way of doing it.

The same for the second part: are you going to make a separate function for each list?

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly!

```
lst = [{'A':'0.1'},{'B':'0.1'},{'C':'0.01'},{'D':'0.0001'},{'E':'0.01'}]
print(dict([list(d.items())[0] for d in lst if list(d.items())[0][1] == '0.1']))
print(dict([list(d.items())[0] for d in lst if list(d.items())[0][1] == '0.01']))
print(dict([list(d.items())[0] for d in lst if list(d.items())[0][1] == '0.0001']))
```

output

```
{'A': '0.1', 'B': '0.1'}
{'C': '0.01', 'E': '0.01'}
{'D': '0.0001'}
```

thanks to Psidom